# Adding a table in phpMyAdmin,shows a lot of errors

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Hello i am still learning and i faced this problem,please how can i fix it ?

> A symbol name was expected! (near "id" ) At least one column
>   definition was expected. (near "id" ) Unexpected beginning of
>   statement. (near "11" ) Unrecognized statement type. (NOT NULL)

```
CREATE TABLE "categories" (
    "id" int(11) NOT NULL, 
    "name" varchar (255) NOT NULL
) "ENGINE" = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = lantin1;
CREATE TABLE "stages" 
( "id" int (11) NOT NULL,
 "categorie_id" int(11) NOT NULL,
 "entreprise" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 "nome" varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
 "description" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 "location" varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
 "contact" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 "contact_email" varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
ALTER TABLE "categories"
ADD PRIMARY KEY ("id");
ALTER TABLE "stages" 
ADD PRIMARY KEY ("id");
ALTER TABLE "categories" 
MODIFY "id" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE "stages" 
MODIFY "id" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

how can i fix it's showing a lot of errors,i am still learning please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove all " characters like below:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id int(11) NOT NULL, 
    name varchar (255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = lantin1;
CREATE TABLE stages 
( id int (11) NOT NULL,
 categorie_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 entreprise varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 nome varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
 description varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 location varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
 contact varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 contact_email varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
ALTER TABLE categories
ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE stages 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE categories 
MODIFY id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE stages 
MODIFY id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```